Tuning loss weight in knowledge distillation
I am implementing a knowledge distillation model. However, the balance and the ratio between different loss components affect the knowledge distillation so much. Are there any good practice to find the optimal loss weights and are there any relevant studies that mention this problem?
Thanks a lot!
